# Publish Web Service from WSDL in Groovy

Tags: groovy, wsdl

What is the simplest way that I can expose a webservice from WSDL using Groovy, like Graffiti does for REST?

I have tried GroovyWS (http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS), it uses a class, but could not find out a way to do that using wsdl.

Groovy-wslite (https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) also only deals with clients.

Please provide a sample if there is such way.

Thanks,
Kasun

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wsimport` to generate the required java classes which you can then expose using Endpoint.publish